# bad dotted quad / DNS

Tags: server, dns, bind

I am trying to redirect a DNS to my VPS (Ubuntu Server 14.04).
I am trying to configure the zones of bind. But I have an error I can't fix ... Any Idea ?

```
toto@serveurVPS:/etc/bind/zones# named-checkzone monsite.com
db.monsite.com  
dns_rdata_fromtext: db.monsite.com:13: near '﻿1.1.1.1': bad dotted quad
db.monsite.com:14: unknown RR type 'A﻿'
zone monsite.com/IN: loading from master file db.monsite.com failed: bad dotted quad
zone monsite.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Here is my file db.monsite.com

```
$TTL 12H
$ORIGIN monsite.com.
@          IN              SOA             serveurVPS. postmaster.monsite.com. (
           2015080801      ; Serial
           8H              ; Refresh
           30M             ; Retry
           4W              ; Expire
           8H              ; Minimum TTL
)
           IN              NS              serveurVPS.
           IN              NS              ######.
           IN              MX      10      mail.monsite.com.
monsite.com.  IN             A ﻿1.1.1.1
ns         IN              A﻿ 1.1.1.1
mail       IN              A 1.1.1.1
www        IN              CNAME           monsite.com.
ftp        IN              CNAME           monsite.com.
ownercheck IN              TXT             "######"
```

Answer (score 1):

When I copied and pasted the above text into Vim, I could see that Line 13 contains a [ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) just preceding the 1.1.1.1 IP address so the address is not considered to be a valid IPv4 address (Line 14 also contains the same character).

Comment: The character (UTF-8 sequence `EF BB BF`) is also used as [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Perhaps the file is concatenated of multiple ones which were using BOM…

Answer (score 0):

remove this entry "monsite.com.  IN             A 1.1.1.1"